# PFObject values may not have class: UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, parse-platform

I have a subclass of PFObject called PFGiveItem.

```
@interface PFGiveItem : PFObject <PFSubclassing>

+(NSString *)parseClassName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *giveItemName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *giveItemImage;

@end
```

When I try to query for images I have saved to Parse, and then save the images to each of my GiveItems, I get an error. This is part of a larger loop which includes its own PFQuery; I'm just isolating this part to keep it simple because the rest of it works.

```
PFQuery *queryForRelatedImages = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"giveItemPhoto"];
[queryForRelatedImages whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:@"pAwHU2e7aw"];
[queryForRelatedImages findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *photos, NSError *error) {
    PFFile *imageFile = photos[0][@"imageFile"];
    NSLog(@"%@", imageFile);
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            newGiveItem.giveItemImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }
    }];
}];
```

When I run this code I get the error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'PFObject values may not have class: UIImage'
```

Which doesn't seem to make sense since the given property of the PFGiveItem class is in fact of the type UIImage.

Answer (score 4):

You must use PFFile, at least for now. It seems PFObjectSubclassing, can't dynamically process a UIImage to PFFile. A simple way of handling this is to use a UIImage public property, and then a PFFile private property.

```
#import "PFObject.h"

@interface PFGiveItem : PFObject <PFSubclassing>
 @property (retain) UIImage *image;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "PFGiveItem.h"
@interface PFGiveItem()
 @property (retain) PFFile *imageFile;
@end

@implementation PFGiveItem
 @dynamic imageFile;
 @synthesize image = _image;
-(UIImage *)image
{
    if (!_image){
        [self fetchIfNeeded];
        _image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self.imageFile getData]];
    }
    return _image;
}
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    _image = image;
    self.imageFile = [PFFile fileWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
}
@end
```

Implementation of the subclassed item is simple, you just work with the UIImage like any other local variable. It helps to fetchInbackground and THEN use the image to keep parse off the main thread:

```
PFGiveItem *giveItem = (PFGiveItem *)[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"TableName" objectId:@"objectId"];
[giveItem fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && object) {
        self.backgroundImageView.image = giveItem.image;
    }
}];
```

Comment: can you explain the last part a little bit? 
what is this doing?

[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"TableName" objectId:@"objectId"]

Comment: and when you say that  PFObjectSubclassing, can't dynamically process a UIImage to PFFile, can you go a little bit into explaining what this means and implies?

Comment: [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"TableName" objectId:@"objectId"] is on method of retrieving an object from Parse if you know it's class name and object ID.

Comment: The Parse SDK performs some exchanges to make the iOS object compatible with their database system. It is capable of automatically converting objects like NSString, NSNumber and others to a format their system can use. UIImage is not one of the automatically supported formats, you must do some of the conversion yourself. Notice I used "@dynamic" for the PFFile *imageFile, but not the UIImage *image. The @dynamic means you want Parse to "magically" do what it needs to do with the setters/getters on their end, but this "magic" only works with certain object types.

Comment: This code worked well for me -- just had to change PFFile to PFFileObject and to this line `self.imageFile = [PFFileObject fileObjectWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];`