# Query images to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to query images in my `UITableview`, but I am having a problem trying to configure the cell.

Comment: You need to reload the table on the main thread, not a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and add a `UIImageView` property to it. Here's an example of what your header file would look like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *icon;

//@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *icon; //Only if you're not using an XIB/storyboard

@end
```

Then, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function would look something similar to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"cellimage";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //the following assumes that your self.images array contains UIImages
    cell.icon.image = [self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Also, be sure to call `reloadData` on the **main thread**.

Comment: but what should i put in the UIImage *yourImage

Comment: Whatever your image is. How do you get your images from your `PFObject`s?

Comment: I'm asking you the question, I don't know what you have stored in your `PFObject`s.

Comment: Ok well see my edit. You need to figure out how your images are being stored put them into the image view accordingly.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052510/pfobject-values-may-not-have-class-uiimage