# PFObject values may not have class: PFFile

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I getting this error "PFObject values may not have class: PFFile" when I try to save a image on a Parse object...

This is the code and the Object:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GGB" ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    PFFile *f = [PFFile fileWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"f_%d_%d.jpg",ctIdx,chIdx] data:d];

    GPChallenge *ch = GPChallenge.object;
    ch.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Challenge %d.%d",(chIdx+1),(ctIdx+1)];
    ch.category = cat;
    ch.image = f;

    [f save];
    [ch save];
```

-- GPChallenge.h

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@class GPCategory;

@interface GPChallenge : PFObject<PFSubclassing>
+ (NSString *)parseClassName;

@property NSString *name;
@property GPCategory *category;
@property PFFile *image;
@end
```

-- GPChallenge.m

```
#import "GPChallenge.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation GPChallenge

@dynamic name;
@dynamic category;
@dynamic image;

+(void)load {
    [self registerSubclass];
}

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"Challenge";
}

@end
```

Any idea?

Comment: You have the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052510/pfobject-values-may-not-have-class-uiimage

Comment: Thanks Fabio, but is not the same problem, I'm already using PFFile.

Comment: Yes you are, but you can't allocate it like you are... You need to pass it like an UIimage before do the PFFile.

Comment: no, that wasn't the problem because the same code works on the app, I forgot to mention that the problem is when the code runs on unit test (XCTestCase).

Comment: BTW PFFiles are not only for images.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are calling [Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:] from your app target.
Have you tried this from you unit test methods?

```
Class MainAppPFFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle]classNamed:@"PFFile"];
PFFile *f = [MainAppPFFile fileWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"f_%d_%d.jpg",ctIdx,chIdx]
```